# Weird error after Magento 2.2.6 update - Magento does not create ImageFactory class (and others)

Tags: magento2, upgrade, dependency-injection, magento2.2.6

After each an every try to update a particular Magento 2.2.5 installation (CE) to 2.2.6 we get the following error:

```
PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Magento\Catalog\Model\View\Asset\ImageFactory::create() in [...]/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Product/Image.php:403
Stack trace:
#0 [...]/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Helper/Image.php(500): Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Image->setBaseFile('/0/1/0100stsc06...')
#1 [...]/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Helper/Image.php(470): Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image->initBaseFile()
#2 [...]/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Helper/Image.php(528): Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image->applyScheduledActions()
#3 [...]/app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto/Smartwave_Filterproducts/templates/owl_list.phtml(74): Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image->getUrl()
#4 [...]/vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php(59): include('/home/myproabr/...')
#5 [...]/vendor/magento/framework/...
```

These are the commands we executed for the update:

```
bin/magento maintenance:enable
composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.2.6 --no-update
composer update -o
rm -rf var/cache/* var/log/* var/page_cache/* generated/
bin/magento cache:clean
bin/magento cache:flush
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento setup:di:compile
bin/magento indexer:reindex
bin/magento maintenance:disable
```

Each and every step, *including `setup:di:compile`*, ran without any errors. However, when opening the front end, the aforementioned error is thrown. The back end works fine.

If you analyse the error message you'll see that the code requires a class called `Magento\Catalog\Model\View\Asset\ImageFactory`. This class does not exist by default but is instead generated as a proxy or interceptor on the fly - or during `setup:di:compile`.

However, when inspecting the `generated/` folder, we can see that there is in fact no file called `generated/code/Magento/Catalog/Model/View/Asset/ImageFactory.php`. However, that file should have been created there (it is there in the 2.2.5 backup for example).

And it's not just this particular class that is missing. There are actually a lot of files missing in the `generated/` folder, judging by the comparison to a working 2.2.5 installation.

So it seems for some reason Magento is unable to identify all required classes for dependency injection - or something similar. Since the file is neither created on demand, nor during `setup:di:compile`. But what could be the reason for that?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it had to do with the usage of `-o` (`--optimize-autoloader`) for the composer (update) operation. With an optimized autoloader, the described problem occurs. Without an optimized autoloader, everything works.

Also noticable are warnings of ambiguous class resolutions when using `-o`, caused by badly programmed Magento 2.x extensions. Maybe these are actually causing the problem (running a live instance without `--optimize-autoloader` is of course not ideal).